# How to run a simple cgi-bin python website on localhost in ubuntu

Tags: python, localhost, cgi-bin

I have the files of a cgi-bin webpage on my computer. And I would like to run the page in my localhost.

I'm completely not experienced. Could you give me a hint, or tutorial, how can I run ready cgi-bin files on my localhost?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) for a webserver, and the tutorial on [their website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html). It took me a little while to figure it out, but it's good for just about anything.

Also, since you tagged python, here's their [intro to cgi](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html)